# How do you now search within YouTube channels?

Tags: youtube, search, youtube-channel

There used to be a search icon when accessing the videos of a channel which would allow to search for videos only in that channel:

[image: search icon]

Since the interface redesign this doesn't seem to be there any more.

How can you search for videos within channels now?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's still in the exact same position

[image: The search icon is found next to the Home/Videos/Playlists/.../About tabs]

For smaller resolutions, you may need to scroll the tabs via the `<` and `>` buttons.

[image: scroll right to find it]

Comment: I can see this on tablet but on desktop this menu isn't there. See screenshot added to question.

Comment: My view *is* the desktop view. Something in your browser broke that causes to hide the navigation + channel banner. Try clearing cache or cookies, but these are specialized solutions for you that are out of scope for StackExchange and better suited to the [product forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/youtube).